# It doesn't work in the root directory

Tags: drush

I'm trying to get Drush to work in a shared environment where I have limited SSH access. I've managed to install Composer and Drush. In PuTTY I can use Drush outside of my Drupal root folder, ie. /var/www/domain.com

Here I can successfully execute: `vendor/bin/drush help` and get the help output in return.

However, if I move (in PuTTY) to my web root folder where my Drupal installation is located: /var/www/domain.com/public_html and try to execute `../vendor/bin/drush help` I get the following message: `: No such file or directory`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the absolute path for vendor/bin/drush, and the absolute path for the Drupal root folder?

Comment: absolute path for vendor/bin/drush: /var/www/sasclan.org/vendor/bin/drush which is a symlink to /var/www/sasclan.org/vender/drush/drush/drush

absolute path for the Drupal root folder: /var/www/sasclan.org/public_html

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should be able to just run `drush help` by itself without having to specify a path to it. If you can't do that, then maybe your environment isn't getting paths set correctly. Something missing from  .bashrc or .profile maybe?

If paths / environment is a problem, I'd try using the phar version of drush - it's a self contained single file, and might work better. You can just download it and run it from anywhere. There's nothing to install:

```
cd ~
wget https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/8.1.11/drush.phar
chmod +x drush.phar
cd /var/www/sasclan.org/public_html
~/drush.phar help
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The drush.phar works when I'm in the `/var/www/sasclan.org/` folder, but if I move to `/var/www/sasclan.org/public_html` it doesn't work. I've also placed, just for testing, the drush.phar in the public_html folder and tested these commands: `php drush.phar help` and `php ../drush.phar help`. (I need to use the prefix php in order to run them). `php drush.phar help` works fine if I'm in `/var/www/sasclan.org/`. If it should work by using `php ../drush.phar help` from the public_html folder it's probably my host where the issue is located.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and using [Drush Launcher](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher) helped me.

> A small wrapper around Drush for your global $PATH.
>
> #### WHY?
>
> In order to avoid dependency issues, it is best to require Drush on a per-project basis via Composer (`composer require drush/drush`). This makes Drush available to your project by placing it at vendor/bin/drush.
>
> However, it is inconvenient to type vendor/bin/drush in order to execute Drush commands. By installing the Drush Launcher globally on your local machine, you can simply type `drush` on the command line, and the launcher will find and execute the project specific version of Drush located in your project's vendor directory.